# How to do a huge search for Primary Key ID's that is used across the database where these Primary Key ID's have similar values in columns

Tags: sql, database, reporting, analytics

BackDrop: We are researching why a number of accounts were missed in a process. We have went back to as far as we have data. We now have a rather large list of accounts that for whatever reason were missed. Now this process without going into too much detail is VERY VERY complex and we need to know why these accounts and only these accounts were missed. As any DataBase we have many many automated procedures that run all the time, so there is really at this point no telling what on earth happened to cause these accounts to get missed. My only bet I think at solving this is to find similarities between these accounts. Obviously we have tried looking at the more common places and have since found nothing.

Issue: I want to use SQL  to return all the tablenames and columnnames in our database Where these list of accounts have the same value in a column or columns of a table. I have created a query to find tablenames, columns, and so forth but dont know how to bring it all together to create one query that will give me all the results I want. I am certain that a cursor will need to be used and lots of inner joining but I am just not sure how this should be done.
Again:
 Lets say I have account numbers 123456 and 654321 and I know our DataBase has 3,000 tables with a column reference to account number with a name  of either AccountNumber, AccountNum, or Account. I want to search and find all tables that have a column with the name AccountNumber, AccountNum, or Account that has a value of 123456 or 654321. Then with these tables, for each table I want to take the rows Where the column whether the name be AccountNumber, AccountNum, or Account has a value of either 123456 and 654321 and then for each of those rows I want to check each column of each row to see if the columns on a row for account number 123456 is eqaul to a column on a row for account number 654321 , if so then I want it to return the column name and the tablename. This way I can see what these accounts have in common.

ADVANCED PORTION:

IF some poor soul is able to do the above then I'd also like to create a query that will return 
  The tablename and when it was updated. I would get the updated value by checking each column in each table and if the column has a type of "timestamp" or a default value of "GetDate()" then that column would be used as updated. In final result set that shows were all changes have happened for those account nubmers it will order by updated.

Comment: Feel free to ask for more details if this was not clear enough. I will check this post again around 7 A.M. to see if any brave souls have attempted this feat.

Comment: sgbd would be nice, for that kind of query travelling in system tables ;) Knowing that you have a GetDate is maybe not enough

Comment: What database and version this is?

Answer (score 0):

A first approach, rustic (I'm not that used to T-SQL, I did more PL/SQL), but which may help you going further, AND TESTED IN SQL SERVER 2008. Hope it works in 2005...)

So, we create two procedures, one calling the other

The provided code can only check, in one time
- for 2 differents IDs
- for all concerned fields (Account, AccountNum, AccountNumber)

The idea (checking for AccountNumber column)

Find the tables (in table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns, which lists your database tables) which have a column with one of the 3 names provided

For every table found :
create a dynamic query :

```
select count(*) from <THE_TABLE> where <Account_column_name> IN (123456 654321);
```

If we have 2 results (mean that our Ids are both present in table), we launch the second procedure, with parameters : `@TableName = <THE_TABLE>`, `@FieldName = <Account_column_name>`, `@FirstId = 123456`, `@SecondId = 654321`

We find the column names for `<THE_TABLE>` (again in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns).
For every column found :
create a dynamic query

```
select count(*) from <THE_TABLE> as T1
inner join <THE_TABLE> as T2 on T1.<COLUMN_NAME> = T2.<COLUMN_NAME>
where T1.<Account_column_name>= 123456
and T2.<Account_column_name>= 654321
```

if `count(*) = 1`, it means that the same value exists in the same column of the same table for the given ids.

In that case, we print `<THE_TABLE>` and `<THE_COLUMN>`

To launch search, in sql management studio, just make

```
EXEC GetSimilarValuesForFieldAndValue  123456, 654321
```

and in the "Messages" part, you should have a list of "results".

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetSimilarValuesForFieldAndValue](@FirstId int, @SecondId int)
AS


DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Count int;
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @FieldName NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR for
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where COLUMN_NAME IN('Account', 'AccountNumber', 'AccountNum');



OPEN db_cursor
FETCH next from db_cursor into @Name, @FieldName
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 begin
     select @sql = 
     N' SELECT @Count=Count(*) FROM ' + @Name +
     N' WHERE ' +@FieldName+' IN (@FirstId,@SecondId)'
     SELECT @params = N'@FieldName NVARCHAR(MAX), @FirstId int, @SecondId int, @Count int out'
     EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @FieldName, @FirstId, @SecondId, @Count OUT
     if (@Count = 2)
     begin
      exec dbo.CompareFields @Name, @FieldName, @FirstId, @SecondId
     end
     FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Name, @FieldName    
 end
 close db_cursor
 DEALLOCATE db_cursor
GO
```

The second one :

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[CompareFields](@TableName NVARCHAR(MAX), @FieldName NVARCHAR(MAX), @FirstId int, @SecondId int)  
as


DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Count int


DECLARE cfCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = ''+@TableName+' '
AND COLUMN_NAME <> ' '+@FieldName+''




OPEN cfCursor
  FETCH next from cfCursor into @ColumnName
  while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    begin
    select @Sql = 
    N' SELECT @Count = count(*) from ' +@TableName + ' T1 '+
    N' INNER JOIN ' + @TableName + ' T2 ON T1.' +@ColumnName + ' = T2.' + @ColumnName +
    N' WHERE T1.' +@FieldName + ' = '+ CAST(@FirstId as varchar) +
    N' AND T2.' + @FieldName + ' = '+CAST(@SecondId as varchar)
    SELECT @Params = 
    N'@TableName VARCHAR(MAX), @ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX), '+
    N'@FieldName VARCHAR(MAX), @FirstId int, @SecondId int, @Count int out'
    exec sp_executesql  @sql, @Params, @TableName, @ColumnName, @FieldName, @FirstId, @SecondId, @Count OUT
    if @Count = 1
    begin
    --print tableName and column Name if value is identic
     print 'Table : ' + @TableName + ' : same value for ' + @ColumnName
    end
    FETCH NEXT FROM cfCursor INTO @ColumnName    
    end
 close cfCursor

 DEALLOCATE cfCursor
GO
```

Comment: What I would do first (if I where you, but I'm not;) ) : create these 2 procedures in your DB and test it with few sample values. This will help you to see if you get too much info (I think it will happen). Then customize, refactor, make it better, and so and so.

Comment: okay so I am kind of wrapping my mind around this and the more I think I have found the steps I think I should take for this analysis.

1. Get List of all tables with column of type int whose value is eqaul tot he account numbers and return TablesName, adn ColumnName into a cursor .

Comment: 2. For each entry in curosr put tableName and Column name in Tablename and Columnname
run dynamic query to find the PK column in the TableName and insert into parameter NAMEOFUIDCOLUMN then run dynamic query 
SELECT NAMEOFUIDCOLUMN , 'TABLENAME' AS TABLENAME FROM Tablename WHERE Columnname IN ([LISTOFACCOUNTNUMBERS) INTO WORKTABLE

Comment: 3. FOREACH DISTINCT TABLENAME IN WORKTABLE get all columns in the result set that all have the same values and return the column names and the table name into another WORK table called THINGSINSCOMMON then once done deallocate the trillions of cursor I would have at this point to run such a query LOL and then select * fROM THINGSINSCOMMON....I think this would work, do you see any flaws to my approach about this matter?

Comment: nameofuidcolumn would be a table that has a primary key column named ID and so I would select ID from the table where the [Account, AccountNUm, or AccountNumber] column had a value of one of the account numbers. Then I would use the values of the UID and select all rows from that table whose UID value was in the UID values's returned and then check the columns to see if any columns have the same value...if that makes it a little bit more clearer

Comment: you're right, I deleted when I understood ;). But the "comparison part" of all the selected rows will be... hum... funny ?

Comment: Just a "detail" with point 1. You'll have to do this in 2 steps at least (get table and column name where column_name in 3 possibilities) + you need to retrieve these datas where all of your AccountNumber are present, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do this for Guids at one point.  Here is the script for doing with Guids.  One sec and I'll work on modifying it to suit your needs:

```
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @value INT

SET @value = '06B8BD6C-A8EC-4EB3-9562-6666EE86952D'

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR
FOR select tbl.Name, cols.name as TableName  FROM sys.columns cols  JOIN 
    sys.tables tbl on cols.object_id = tbl.object_id
    where system_type_id = 36

OPEN table_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor 
INTO @table, @column;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ''' + @Table + '''  AS TBL,''' + 
@column + ''' AS COL FROM [' + @table + '] 
WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE ' + @column + ' = ''' + CAST(@value AS VARCHAR(50)) + ''''

    print @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor 
INTO @table, @column;

END

CLOSE table_cursor
DEALLOCATE table_cursor
```

**Updated to handle for searching on a field name:**

```
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @value UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

SET @value = --ENTER YOUR ACCOUNT NUMBER HERE

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR

select tbl.Name, cols.name as TableName  FROM sys.columns cols  JOIN 
    sys.tables tbl on cols.object_id = tbl.object_id
    where cols.Name = 'AccountNumber' 
    OR cols.Name = 'AccountNum' OR cols.Name = 'Account'

OPEN table_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor 
INTO @table, @column;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ''' + @Table + '''  AS TBL,''' + @column + 
    ''' AS COL FROM [' + @table + '] WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE ' + @column + ' = ''' + CAST(@value AS VARCHAR(50)) + ''''
    print @sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor 
INTO @table, @column;

END

CLOSE table_cursor
DEALLOCATE table_cursor
```